# string concatenation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a HTML string in the following way:

```
htmlString = '<html>';
var headerString = "image1";
var sImage = "Android_images/"+headerString+".png";
htmlString += '<img src='+sImage+' />';
htmlString = '</html>';
```

I need to dynamically append a image string, but it shows:

```
<img src=Android_images/dfdfd.png />
```

Comment: Why are you using `<html>` tags?

Comment: What exactly you mean by image string? Is it the `img` element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're re-setting the variable on this last line:

```
htmlString = '</html>';
```

Add a `+` and it'll work:

```
var htmlString = '<html>';
var headerString = "image1";
var sImage = "Android_images/" + headerString + ".png";
htmlString += '<img src="' + sImage + '" />';
htmlString += '</html>';
```

Also, why are there `<html>` tags here?

Comment: i am building webview for titanium

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var htmlString = '<html>';
var headerString = "image1";
var sImage = "Android_images/"+headerString+".png";
htmlString += '<img src="'+sImage+'" />';
htmlString += '</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlString = '<html>';

htmlString += '</hmtl>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined htmlString as a variable before you started using it:

```
var htmlString = '<html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always use `var`.

Not using var has two major drawbacks:

- Accessing a variable within a function that is not defined within
  that function will cause the interpreter to look up the scope chain
  for a variable with that name until either it find one or it gets to
  the global object (accessible in browsers via window) where it will
  create a property. This global property is now available everywhere,
  potentially causing confusion and hard-to-detect bugs;
- Accessing an undeclared variable will cause an error in ECMAScript 5
  strict mode.

[Working Perfectly here](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/zYmsk/1/) and in last line you should use `+=`:

```
htmlString += '</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
var htmlString = '<html>';
var headerString = "image1";
var sImage = "Android_images/"+headerString+".png";
htmlString += '<img src="'+sImage+'" />';
htmlString += '</html>';
```

"htmlString" will contain below output

```
<html><img src="Android_images/image1.png" /></html>
```

think it will help you.